# Understanding sequence of $\sigma$ algebra and their union

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

In relation to another question of mine, I thought to create this question in order to get some help in visualising through an example the question of a sequence of $\sigma-$ algebras and their union.

So I will start from a fast recall: we have $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ a probability space. We then call $\mathcal{F}_n$ a sequence of $\sigma-$algebras in $\mathcal{F}$.
Then
$$\mathcal{G}_n = \sigma\left(\bigcup_{k = n}^{+\infty} \mathcal{F}_k\right)$$
is the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathcal{F}_n, \mathcal{F}_{n+1}, \ldots$

The tail sigma algebra (or also: terminal) is instead
$$\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{F}_n) = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \mathcal{G}_n$$

Also $\mathcal{F}_n$ should be the sigma algebra generated by the random variable $X_n$.

**A possible example to visualise**

I don't know if this could fit the theory, but I try.

Say I have a die of four faces. Then $\Omega = \{1; 2; 3; 4\}$

After one throw, I clearly expect to get $\{1\}$ or $\{2\}$ or $\{3\}$ or $\{4\}$.

After two throws I expect those possibilities $\{1; 1\}$ or $\{1; 2\}$ and so on up to $\{4; 4\}$.

And this goes on for $n$ throws.

At this point I ask: is it possible from this example to visualize what a sequence of sigma algebras are? Contained into $\mathcal{F}$. How?

Is it possible to visualize $\mathcal{G}_n$ too? How? What about the tail sigma algebra?

I think this could be a good way to visualise certain concepts which usually do lie in pages without any application or example.

Comment: I think $\Omega$ should not be $\{1,2,3,4\}$ but $\{1,2,3,4\}^{\Bbb N}.$ And $X_n:\Omega\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ could be the $n$-th projection.

Comment: @AnneBauval This is because I can have $N$ throws, right? I wrote $\Omega$ as if I had just one throw

Comment: I agree. But my $\Bbb N$ is not a number $N,$ it is the set of all natural numbers, so that $\{1,2,3,4\}^{\Bbb N}$ is the set of all possible results of an *infinite* sequence of throws.

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry, I meant that too but with a bad writing / expression. So, after this could we come up with something as I asked for, or my problem is not good?

Comment: I don't know what $\mathcal F$ and $P$ should be, but they seem irrelevant. If I am not wrong, $\mathcal G_n$ is the set of subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ such that for every sequence $x\in A$, $A$ also contains every sequence $y$ s.t. $\forall k\ge n,y_k=x_k.$ So, $\bigcup_n\mathcal G_n$ is the the set of subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ such that for every sequence $x\in A$, $A$ also contains every sequence $y$ eventually equal to $x.$

Comment: $\mathcal{F}$ is the sigma algebra and $P$ is the measure (in this case a probability measure). We need them in order to have a solid space in which to operate. Thank you for the comment, I'll reason about it!

Comment: You are welcome, but I am absolutely certain you don't need them to define $\mathcal F_n$ (the [$\sigma$-algebra generated by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebra_generated_by_a_function) $X_n$) and your unions and intersections.